# Why new version of MySQL installation file shows the old version prompt?

Tags: mysql, linux, server, ubuntu-18.04

The current installed MySQL version on my server (ubuntu 18.04) is 5.7, I need to update it to 8th version .. I'm following [this](https://thishosting.rocks/how-to-upgrade-mysql-ubuntu/) instruction.

I'm at `/home/martin#` path and I executed `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` as well. I've also executed this `wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb` and the installation file downloaded correctly.

Now, when I run this `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb`, I get a prompt with old version:

[image]

See? it's still `mysql-5.7`. Why?

The expected result (based on the instruction) should be `mysql-8.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it says "currently selected: mysql-5.7", but what happens when you actually select that item? As this is the Package configuration step it may well be that this is actually what's going to do the actual configuration replacement, so replacing 5.7 with the more recent install

Comment: So, you mean I have to press enter?

Comment: Yeah you were right .. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFTtn.png) is the next promp I got after pressing enter.